# In static member variable initializer why is static member function (not the global one) called?

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, static-methods

What should be the output of the following program?

```
#include<iostream>

int foo()
{
  return 10;
}

struct foobar
{
  static int x;
  static int foo()
  {
    return 11;
  }
};

int foobar::x = foo();

int main()
{
  std::cout<<foobar::x<<endl;
}
```

I have run the program but got answer `11`, but I think the correct answer should be `10`. I don't know why `foo()` in `int foobar::x = foo();` should be static function, please help me understand this. Further examples on uses of static function would be preferred!

Answer (score 3):

Because the initializer expression is in the scope of struct `foobar`, so `foobar::foo()` will be called here.

From the standard, `$9.4.2/2 Static data members [class.static.data]`:

> The initializer expression in the
>   definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class (3.3.7). Example:
>
> ```
> class process {
> static process* run_chain;
> static process* running;
> };
> process* process::running = get_main();
> process* process::run_chain = running;
> ```
>
> The static data member `run_chain` of class `process` is defined in global
>   scope; the notation `process::run_chain` specifies that the member
>   `run_chain` is a member of class `process` and in the scope of class
>   `process`. In the static data member definition, the initializer
>   expression refers to the static data member `running` of class `process`.
>   —end example ]